# Is there a _setting.scss in bootstrap like zurb foundation does?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

When I worked with foundation, it offers a _setting file and I can change whole foundation default style to my preferred way. Is there such a setting file for bootstrap? 
If there isn't one, how do you guys apply your style along the way? Override default by rewriting it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with the less files instead, but there should be some less/scss-file in the package named "variables.less(/scss)", where you can change most of the crucial things ;)

Comment: awsome! thanks for the tip. Now how do you structure it so that when you update your boostrap, updates won't replace your own style?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize bootstrap on the site http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: you don't really know what you would need at beginning. you style while you work on the project.